# Exception with join columns just on one server

Tags: php, apache, doctrine, mysql

I have multiple development instances, on different servers, and for some reason, one of them I get the error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Cannot find a field on 'models\CampaignEntry' that is mapped to column 'campaigns'. Either the field does not exist or an association exists but it has multiple join columns. in /var/www/html/system/library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 371
```

The code for MappingException.php is here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php

I can't really see where the error is, because the database structure and data is the same across the different servers. The code is also the same, since it's under Git control and I have the same branch in all of them. Configuration options are the same, and the httpd.conf is the exact same thing.

Where else could I look to find the answer for this? Is it possible that a MySQL configuration be the issue in this case? Maybe something else server related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment contaning the annotations for the field must be a docblock comment, with 2 asterisks instead of one. This is wrong and will display the error mentioned:

```
 /* 
  * @var string $field
  *
  * @Column(name="field", type="string")
  */
private $field;
```

This is correct:

```
/** 
  * @var string $field
  *
  * @Column(name="field", type="string")
  */
private $field;
```